# How to use 3D Touch on Simulator of Iphone 6 and 6S

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, 3dtouch

iPhone 6S and 6S plus has new feature called "3D Touch".
 How to simulate 3D Touch on iOS Simulator v/s Long Press on Simulator in MAC.

Comment: you'd think the new laptop touchpad would simulate it